# I need to put my LI array element into a UL but I cant

Tags: javascript, arrays

HERE IS THE CODE:
I need to do a couple of things but I am pretty new coding :S. 
First I need to format the li elements I am loading into the array into a UL. them I need also to create a loop where I can print those 20 array elements repeating them to display 2300 elements. Thanks :)

```
var _objetsOfArray = new Array();

 var darFormato = function (numero){
    var numero = document.createElement("li");
    var contenido = document.createTextNode(i);
    numero.appendChild(contenido);
    document.body.insertBefore(numero); 
 }

for (i = 0; _objetsOfArray.length < 20; i++ ){
    _objetsOfArray.push (i);
    darFormato(i);

};
```

Comment: you override the passed in variable with an instantiation of a li element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved it for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4Vec/

```
var count = 2300;
while (count){
    var _objectsOfArray = [],
        ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        item.innerText = i;
        _objectsOfArray.push(item);
        ul.appendChild(_objectsOfArray[i]);
        count --;
    }
    //do something with UL
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
}
```

If you have a precreated list, you could use innerHTML and parse it accordingly.

My sample just prints a ul with 20 Li elements with the text node set to the index of the node

Edit:  New Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4Vec/1/

Comment: Great Fallenreaper!! its working great! thanks...now I need to repeat this 20 elements many times to make a list of 2300 elements..can I do a while using a count?

Comment: Are you trying to create 2300 uls of 20 lis?

Comment: if you are doing 1 UL, you can change the `i` from 20 to 2300

Comment: no, I need to display those 20 elements many times to complete 2300 places in the screen..just repeat them randomly..

Comment: im not sure if you wanted _objectsOfArray to be at most 20, so each loop, it recreates the array.  In this example though, `_objectsOfArray` is actually not needed at all.  If you wanted that to be a global array, which will account for all 2300 items, that is a different story.  It would need to be moved outside the while loop, and everything would work

Comment: Yes Fallenreaper..thats exactly what I need..but I cant see all 2300 repetitions :(..

Comment: You still need to render it to the screen.  In my jsfiddle, i just did:  `$("body").append(ul);` but that was using jQuery.  you could do something at the end of the while that says:  document.write(ul);  ill adjust my post

Comment: i put the document.write(ul); and it shows me 2300 times this: [object HTMLUListElement]

Comment: use:  `document.body.appendChild(ul);`

Comment: jaja nice!! thanks Fallenreaper, its working perfect :)

Comment: np DanArg :)  Make sure to upvote and select as correct answer if mine is the answer which helped you. :)

Comment: just the check icon right? let me know if i did ok..I am newbie ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use this on a page to generate some dynamic links:

```
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

and here is the script

```
    var myData = [
"item1",
        "item2"
]
function createItems()
{
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++)
    {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&pagesize=30&q=" + myData[i].toLowerCase();
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.innerHTML = myData[i];
        li.appendChild(a);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
createItems();
```

where I changed the hrefs to SO :)

I hope taking a look will help you